# Adding microphone/amplifier to Gumstix Overo Earth COM?

Tags: soldering, amplifier, speakers, microphone, gumstix

I am new to hardware hacking in general.  I have a Gumsitx Overo Earth COM and a Palo35 expansion board with audio in/audio out capabilities.  According to [Gumstix's wikipage on audio input](http://wiki.gumstix.org/index.php?title=AudioIn), the Palo35 board has "stereo audio in," but not a "stereo headset jack."  I know that I am going to need an amplifier if I want to add a microphone, but I am not sure how to actually integrate an amplifier or microphone onto the board.  I have searched for answers on Google for how to do this but I have not found many helpful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Overo COMs have line-level inputs and outputs. You're right that if you want to drive anything other than a line in on a stereo or amplified speakers, you will need to hook up an amplifier. It can be as simple as a little transistor amplifier or LM386 op-amp, or as complex as the guitar amp on "Back to the Future." :-)

Adding a microphone input to the COM will also need an amplifier, as you've already mentioned. If you just want to get up and running quickly, I suggest something like [this SparkFun kit](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/8872); it's only mono, but you can connect both the left and right inputs of the COM to the output of this without trouble.